# X ≼ Y ≼ Z and |X| = |Z|. Prove |Y|=|Z|.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad X \preceq Y \preceq Z$ and $|X| = |Z|$. Prove that $|Y|=|Z|$.

Just started on cardinalities. Not sure about this one.

Am I right if I do something along the lines of: we define injective functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$. Composite $fg$ is bijective and, hence, surjective. It must be the case that $g$ is also surjective. By definition, we already know that $g$ is injective. Therefore, we have $g:Y\to Z$ is bijective $\implies |Y|=|Z|$.

Comment: Because I'm uninitiated in the subject, what does the notation mean?

Comment: @Clayton: $X\preccurlyeq Y$ means that there is an injection from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks! I guessed from context that is what it should mean, but I didn't know for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be a bit cautious, here. In general, knowing only that $|X|=|Z|$ and that $h:X\to Z$ is injective isn't enough to conclude that $h$ is bijective. (Consider the map $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ given by $n\mapsto n+1$, for example.) For finite sets, we can draw that conclusion, but if you haven't proved that yet, then you shouldn't use it as a result. Now, it's true that if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are such that $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is surjective, then so is $g$. Hence, your conclusion is fine, so long as you know that an injection between finite sets of equal cardinality is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks Cameron. Question: what more would I have to do if it was not specified that the sets were finite?

Comment: If it was not specified that the sets were finite, then you'd want to show that $X\preccurlyeq Z$ as you did, then note that $Z\preccurlyeq X$ since $|X|=|Z|$, and finally refer to [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem) (arguably the most useful theorem of all theorems about cardinality).

Comment: I realised that the sets were not actually finite when I looked at my problem set again so removed it from the post. Very careless of me. But what you have said makes perfect sense because we only just covered the Cantor-Bernstein theorem last class. Thanks once again.